# I would like to know if this game is winnable for black?

Tags: middlegame, evaluation, beginner

Black to move but unsure of the pieces that would give black a better advantage. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
r5k1/pp1qpr1p/3p2p1/2pP4/1n2P3/1P2N1Pb/2PQ1P1P/3RR1K1 b - - 0 1
```

Comment: Are you sure there is no mistake in the board position? Black is simply a piece up with equal pawns! That's clearly winning.

Answer (score 5):

Black has an overwhelming advantage and should win easily. Being up by a whole piece is a huge advantage that basically can't be overcome by purely positional considerations.

The most straightforward way for Black to win is to try to trade pieces and end up in an endgame where he has one piece to White's zero; a win at that point would be trivial.

He could also try for a kingside attack, since White's light squares are very weak.

Answer (score 3):

The above position is 100% won for Black-White will need a miracle to scrape a draw, not to mention win!

How do you win this?

The best rule **in a won position** is to destroy the opponents counter-play.

Here White has no counter-play whatsoever, but could try something with `f4+Nc4` so he can push `e5` and try to "get lucky".

I would start with `1..Rf3` since the rook can not be dislodged from this post. White will have to exchange it but this is good for Black.

Remember, when you are a piece up always exchange pieces **but avoid exchanging the pawns** as this helps the weaker side to achieve draw.

Anyway, after `1..Rf3` White must try `Nc4` and push `e5` to get some play, but as soon as knight lands on `c4` Black plays `...b5` and again White has no counter-play.

After that, Black needs to improve the position of the weakest piece in his setup-here it is knight on `b4`. I would post it on `e5` or `d4`.

After reaching this setup you will win by a tactical sacrifice.

Here is a sample line that could illustrate how things would go:

```
[fen "r5k1/pp1qpr1p/3p2p1/2pP4/1n2P3/1P2N1Pb/2PQ1P1P/3RR1K1 b - - 0 1"]

1...Rf3 2.Nc4 b5 3.Ne3 Raf8 4.Re2 Na6 5.Ra1 Nb8 6.Qa5 a6 7.Qb6 Qc8 8.c4 b4 9.Qa5 Nd7 10.Qxa6 Qxa6 11.Rxa6 Ne5 12.Ra7 R8f7 13.Ra1  Ng4 14.Nxg4 Bxg4 15.Rb2 ( 15.Rb1 Rxg3+ 16.hxg3 Bxe2-+ ) 15...Bh3! 16.Rd1 Kg7! 17.Rdd2 Kf6 18.Rd1 Ke5 19.Rdd2 Rf8! 20.Rdd1 Ra8! 21.Re1 Ra3 22.Reb1 Kxe4 23.Re2+ Kd3 24.Reb2 ( 24.Rxe7 Ra2! ) Kc3 25.Kh1 Ra1! 26.Kg1 ( 26.Rxa1 Kxb2 ) 26...Rxb1 27.Rxb1 Kc2 28.Re1 Rxb3 29.f4 Rb1 0-1
```

This example contains some highly instructive moments. Pay attention how Black limits White's counter-play and how he constantly improves his inactive pieces-his knight, rook and king. Once he activated all of his pieces, tactical blows came naturally and Black was able to win effortlessly.

In a won position your main goal is to suppress all active moves your opponent has. Once you do that, your decisive advantage will "kick in" eventually. You see, once your opponent has no counter-play all you have to do is improve the position of your inactive pieces and the rest comes naturally.

This was just a sample line-I have no space to analyze all possible continuations but by following my advises you can learn on your own how to win this position.

If you have further questions leave a comment.

Best regards.